# How can an Ebike speedsensor regulate the voltage for its throttle?

Tags: automotive, sensors

I want to rebuilt my High-Speed Ebike after it went down.

I tried a Chinese out-of-the-box controller ($40) but it only rotates the 36DC 400W motor at 3 speeds.

Since I want to enhance the bike (GPS, RasPi) I might better intergrate the whole thing, so now I'm thinking of a bare PCB to regulate the speed of the 3 phase motor. Regulation is done by an analogue pot with knob. [Could be this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D9B6J78)

I'm looking for a way to replace the knob with a electronic version, that takes its input from the speedsensor. This is magnetic switch (Hall?), normal open.

So I'm looking for something that builds up a voltage between 1.8 and 4.9v, depending on the frequency of pulses from the sensor.

I hope this makes sense and somebody is able to get me on track for a solution. 
TIA!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be related to programming at all.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I can live with closing the question, while it's been answered. I do not agree completely with the 'not appear to be related to programming' statement. Regulating the voltage does have to do with programming (be it a few lines to accomplish this).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works the other way around. There's no voltage to be 'build up', rather there should be a max voltage (5V) availlable that's dimmed to lower levels by a 10K digital potentiometer. The lever is controlled by a SPI-signal that's generated by the Pi.

Microchip Technology has quite a bunch of them: https://www.microchip.com/paramChartSearch/chart.aspx?branchID=11026

Still have to work this out on a board, though.